# Flask with subdomain breaks links to static resources

Tags: flask, subdomain

I added subdomains support:

1. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
    127.0.0.1       subdomain.test.com
```

2. Flask config:

```
    SERVER_NAME = 'test.com:5005'
```

3. Blueprint:

```
@app_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET'], subdomain='<subdomain_name>') 
def index(subdomain_name):
    return redirect(url_for('app.index'))
```

It successfully finds the route but when it loads the template app.html into the browser it can't resolve the static resource:

Instead of

```
<script src="http://subdomain.test.com:5005/static/dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

it resolves as

```
<script src="http://test.com:5005/static/dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

and can't find it.

What am I missing?

Update. I updated the hosts file according to Sean's answer. But now Flask can't find the endpoint "app.index" that I'm redirecting to.

I specified it as:

```
@app_blueprint.route('/app', methods=['GET'], subdomain='<subdomain_name>')
@app_blueprint.route('/app/<path:path>', methods=['GET'], subdomain='<subdomain_name>')
def index(path = None, subdomain_name=None):
    return render_template('app.html', subdomain_name=subdomain_name)
```

This endpoind can be hit if I use /app in browser directly but redirection doesn't work and other things can'be found either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add `test.com` to your `/etc/hosts` alias:

```
127.0.0.1       subdomain.test.com  test.com
```

You told Flask that you're mounted at `test.com` and so it mounted the `/static` routes there ... but your network layer doesn't know where `test.com` is because you haven't told it where it lives.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But now I have another problem - for some reason, it can't find it (404). I was wrong, previously it threw some other exception.

Comment: I also have now the following exception "Server-side ERROR:  Could not build url for endpoint 'app.index'. Did you forget to specify values ['path', 'subdomain_name']?" I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, never mind, fixed the problem providing subdomain_name as a parameter when do a redirect.